# HTML5 "range" input not displaying correctly with Jquery-mobile

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I am trying to use JQuery mobile. The "range" input is not displayed correctly in both chrome and the opera mobile simulator. I am getting double sliders instead. In chrome I am getting this

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/29535923/desktop%20view.jpg

and on the opera mobile I am getting this

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/29535923/mobileview.jpg

I used the standard code fom Jquery mobile website. which is like

```
 <label for="slider-1">Input slider:</label>
 <input type="range" name="slider-1" id="slider-1" value="60" min="0" max="100" />
```

Please advise what is wrong here.
Many thanks,

Comment: Can you provide your entire markup. What follows these lines? You might also try using `<div data-role="fieldcontain">` in your markup.

Comment: @andleer well thank you for reply. I didn't think about other code. I am using it as part of a big JSP (280 lines) file. I have now spotted the error but don't how does it make sense. the problem is with PrintWriter:::  
     outt.println("some thing");
     //where outt is object. PrintWriter outt = response.getWriter();)
when I removed this outt.println(); The range input control become normal.